# Join partially adjacent faces to make a plane with a hole in the middle

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, faces

[image]

I've got four cuboids placed next to each other in the following pattern to create a square with a hole in the middle. I have joined the four objects together already. How do I join the top faces to make each corner look like this?

[image]

Comment: I think you’re better off with a slightly different approach. What I would do is just make a cuboid, then inset a face on the top, extrude it inward through the other side, and then use knife intersect. I might also just inset faces on both sides, and then use Bridge Edge Loops.

Comment: @TheLabCat problem is that i already have a whole model with the right sizes and alignment and stuff that was built this way; i made a simplified example for this question.

Comment: I see. Well, IDK what’s joined and what’s not, but two things: First, the inner corner edges will not create vertices along the inner ring edges by themselves through any operator I’ve used. Second, 3D faces cannot have holes in them. SketchUp fakes it.

Comment: @TheLabCat ah well that explains it then. I didn't know faces could not be perforated. What I am trying is probably unnecessary in that case.